# gRaphael-linechart

Tags: graphael

When sending single data values for first line data to a graphael line chart, the graph is not displaying and the browser stopped running and when passing symbols other than "circle" like "square","disc" then also graph is not displaying
eg:

```
var line=r.linechart(10,10,300,220,[[5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[0],[3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 8]],[[8],[12, 32, 23, 15, 17, 27, 22],[8], [10, 20, 30, 25, 15, 28]],{nostroke:false,axis"0 0 1 1",symbol:["circle","circle","circle","circle"],smooth:true});
```

This is not working in any of the browsers, only when passing the single values for the first line only it is not running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The larger dataset for the x-values and y-values needs to be listed first in your multi-dimensional array.

i.e.  [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7,8],[5],[0]], [[12, 32, 23, 15, 17, 27, 22],[10, 20, 30, 25, 15, 28],[8],[8]]

Just read about this problem here: http://www.exratione.com/2011/10/a-few-tips-for-graphael-line-charts.php

Comment: will the linechat accept morethan 10 lines? i am trying to do so but no possible way to come up with the issue

Answer (score 0):

It appears that symbols other than circle have been deprecated, and break the chart. Circle or nothing, unfortunately.